# Why in Magento EE the DOB and Gender configuration are "disabled"?

Tags: magento-enterprise, customer

I was looking for a way to enable DOB and Gender and well I saw that there is a configuration under *System → Configuration → Customers → Cusotmers Configuration → Name and Address Options* and there should be two dropdowns with the configuration for DOB and Gender. The thing I saw is that in app/code/core/Enterprise/Customer/etc/system.xml is that they are not configurable through any of the three scopes (Default, Website and Store), the code here:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Magento Enterprise Edition
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Magento Enterprise Edition License
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_EE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://www.magentocommerce.com/license/enterprise-edition
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    Enterprise
 * @package     Enterprise_Customer
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2014 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
 * @license     http://www.magentocommerce.com/license/enterprise-edition
 */
-->
<config>
    <sections>
        <customer>
            <groups>
                <address>
                    <fields>
                        <street_lines>
                            <show_in_default>0</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>0</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </street_lines>
                        <prefix_show>
                            <show_in_default>0</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>0</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </prefix_show>
                        <middlename_show>
                            <show_in_default>0</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>0</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </middlename_show>
                        <suffix_show>
                            <show_in_default>0</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>0</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </suffix_show>
                        <dob_show>
                            <show_in_default>0</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>0</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </dob_show>
                        <taxvat_show>
                            <show_in_default>0</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>0</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </taxvat_show>
                        <gender_show>
                            <show_in_default>0</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>0</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </gender_show>
                    </fields>
                </address>
            </groups>
        </customer>
    </sections>
</config>
```

I hope someone has the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Magento EE you can change DOB, Gender and other customer attributes behavior in `Customers -> Attributes -> Manage Customer Attributes`.

Both DOB and Gender fields are not visible in frontend by default. You can make them visible by changing "Show on Frontend" to "Yes" in attribute edit form.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, with Magento EE, you can manage the customer attributes (Add, remove, enable visibility to frontend)... So we don't need the other options.

Answer (score 0):

Go to *System -> Configuration -> Customer -> Customer Configuration -> Name and Address Options*

Now you need to change *Show date of Birth* from **Optional** to **Required**. Same has to do with gender.